# Installing Windows over Ubuntu on Surface Pro

Tags: windows, ubuntu

I have a somewhat interesting predicament.

One day I decided as I usually do with all my computers that putting ubuntu on it as a main OS would be a good idea. As always, I regret this decision within a few days and usually spend upwards of a day correcting it because I'm always plagued by issues reverting back to windows. No I don't learn from my mistakes very well, but I try to look at it as learning to fix new things. :)

Anyway, this is my problem, I have a surface pro running Ubuntu. There is no windows recovery partition, the SSD was completely formatted. I want to go back to windows.

I have a USB stick, another windows computer, a windows 7 ISO, and a windows 8 ISO to work with. I don't have an external optical drive so an install disc is out of the question. No local stores have one.

I have tried several methods, which I will list below:

1: copy the contents of the windows 7 ISO to a usb formatted as ntfs and made bootable through cmd

2: used unetbootin

3: used winusb

4: created an ntfs partition on the SSD and put the windows 7 iso on it and did something with grub? I can't remember the exact details of this one

Shouldn't I just be able to plug in the bootable windows 7 USB to my surface and boot from it? Why is it so damn difficult to figure out? And why does the surface not have a proper damn BIOS? ARGHHHH

So yeah, any thoughts? Fixes?

Is it possible to install windows from a VM? 
Thank you to anyone that helps!

Comment: You are going to find it extremely difficult to move to Windows 7 on a Windows Surface Pro because of driver support, guess what, the device wasn't designed for Windows 7.  The Surface actually does have a proper BIOS, actually UEFI, but we will just called that symnatics.  You need to remember what you did to grub, that might be vitle information.

Comment: I'm a little confused here. Did you actually try creating a Windows 8 bootable USB installer or not? Because that's what you should do.

Answer (score 3):

You can install Windows 7 on the Surface Pro, the Surface doesn't support BIOS initialization which is required to boot Windows 7.

**Windows 7 Setup hangs at "Starting Windows" on Surface Pro**

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2828074/en-us

> The Surface Pro is a Class 3 UEFI device that does not support legacy
>   BIOS Interrupt 10 (INT 10H) video transitioning and it requires
>   Windows 8 or later operating systems to run.

You need a Windows 8 (x64) USB drive to install Windows again.

Answer (score 1):

- Format a USB to FAT32 (if you're using gparted in ubuntu, make sure it has the "boot" label)
- Take the windows 8 ISO and mount it somehow, or find a way to extract the files within it (simply placing the ISO on the USB will NOT WORK. I mounted the ISO and copied the contents to the USB.)
- Turn off the surface
- Turn on the surface, holding the volume down key
- Change "secure boot" to ENABLED
- I think I cleared the keys and then made new ones? Like there are two options when you enable secure boot, I did the second one and then did the first one, and then pressed exit
- When the surface resets and shows "SURFACE" splash, PRESS AND RELEASE volume down
- It should now boot from USB

Comment: If you're the same Trevor who posted the question, please contact the team and have your accounts merged: http://superuser.com/contact